# R: enlarge a transactions plot

Tags: r, plot, transactions, data-mining, arules

Hi I need help with this. When I put

[image]

I got these error.

BUT, I'm trying to plotting it on a knit html document and I want something like this:

[image]

What should i pass as a parameter to the plot function???

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when posting R questions.

Comment: Change the font size, or increase your canvas size.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(arulesViz)
data("Groceries")
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.5))
```

Adjust the height of your graphics device

```
f <- function(height) { 
  pdf(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"), height = height)  
  plot(rules, method="grouped") 
  dev.off() 
  shell.exec(tf) 
}
f(5)  # too small
f(10) # better height
```

or try using an interactive plot

```
sel <- plot(rules, method="grouped", interactive=TRUE)
```

Comment: nice function +1, you could also abbreviate the labels, `Groceries <- arulesViz::abbreviate(Groceries)`

Comment: it doesn't work because im trying to plot it on a knit html document :(

Comment: @IvanG4Life And it's not possible to define the height for a plot there? Please edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example of what you got.

Comment: @IvanG4Life Replace `\`\`\`{r}` by `\`\`\`{r, fig.height=20}` for example.